# Icon Alignment issue

Tags: html, css, 960.gs

I have a 960 grid template and I have my logo far left and want to position some icons far right in the header. I cannot for the life in me achieve this and would like some help please.

This is the header code:

```
<body>
  <div class="container_12">
    <header>
        <h1><a href="/">some title</a></h1>
    </header>
```

And here is the CSS for this section:

```
header,
h2 {background: url(img/header.gif) bottom left no-repeat; padding: 20px 0 10px 0;}
header{height:45px;}
h1 {background: url(img/logo.png) top left no-repeat; width:140px; height: 31px; display:block; text-indent:-999em; font-size:0;}
.small p {font-size: 12px; }
p.success {padding: 10px; background: #adefa0; font-size: 16px;}
```

I wanted to put a twitter, facebook and linkedin icon on the far right which are in my /img/ folder but cannot get the alignment right and everything is far right and a mess.

Can someone please help.

Thanks,
Philip

Comment: There's a lot of irrelevant code here and not enough relevant code. Can you put up a demo on http://jsfiddle.net and/or post the header markup and CSS in its entirety? For instance, I don't see markup for any of these icons, or any CSS that even suggests right alignment.

Comment: Maybe you could put and try it on http://jsfiddle.net/ and link it up here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried putting them in a container that is floated to the right in your header div?

```
.icon_container {
   float: right;
   margin-right: 10px;
}

<body>
  <div class="container_12">
    <header>
        <div class="icon_container">
            <a href="http://example.com">Example</a> |
            <a href="http://foo.com">Foo</a> |
            <a href="http://bar.com">Bar</a>
        </div>
        <h1><a href="/">some title</a></h1>
    </header>
```

Comment: You might want to give it a width as well if the icons wrap to a new line as the browser width is reduced.

Comment: Works a treat and thank you VERY much....if I wanted to use text links as opposed to icons would I be okay with <p> tags, replacing the <img src> tags?

Comment: No. Paragraphs are block level elements; you'd want to use spans for text links, perhaps making them `inline-block` if you want to make them the same width.

Comment: Could you provide me with an example as per what you did above please. Thank you

Comment: Sorry, but if I also wanted to sepeate these text links i.e. link1 | link 2 | link 3 and use an image (which is a grey line) how would I put all of this together please?

Comment: I wouldn't use an image, I'd simply use spans and the vertical bar character.

Comment: I've updated to just use a series of links. That should be a good start for you (and may be enough). Play with margin/padding/width, etc. until you get just what you want.  If they need to a fixed width, use `inline-block` and specify the width (normal inline elements resize to fit their contents, so you need `inline-block` to get both width and inline positioning).

Comment: That is brill and BIG thank you for all your help

Answer (score 0):

```
<header>
    <h1><a href="/">some title</a></h1>
    <ul id='socialnetworkmenu'>
        <li><a href="twitter.com"><img src='img/twitter.png' alt='Twitter'/></a>
        <li><a href="facebook.com"><img src='img/facebook.png' alt='Facebook'/></a>
        <li><a href="LinkedIn.com"><img src='linkedin.png' alt='LinkedIn'/></a>
    </ul>
</header>

#socialnetworkmenu{float:right}
#socialnetworkmenu li{float:left; padding:5px}
header h1{float:left}
```

This should get you on the right track

Comment: This is all well and good until (`h1` width + `ul` width) > `header` width. Might want to explicitly set `(max-)width`s, use absolute positioning, or markup the list before the heading.